# jquery fadeIn change content and fadeout with opacity?

Tags: javascript, jquery, opacity, fadein, fadeout

Being new at javascript and jquery this one is throwing me for a loop.

I would like to have a fluid fadeOut change html fadeIn function but it doesn't seem to be working as I would have expected it.

I have a div container for content that is populated by an ajax request using jquery. This works fine.

My end goal is to make an ajax request, fade out the current content in the div container, and fade in new content

code is currently as follows

```
$("#middle").fadeOut('slow',function(){
    $("#middle").html(data).fadeIn('slow');
});
```

I have tried the same with opacity and have the same problem. It seems opacity is the way I want to go about it as it leaves the size of the div container alone. The answer has to be simple.

As said before I would prefer to do it with opacity but either way would do if it works. I have the same issues with both.

Issue seemed to be a browser caching issue. It is no longer occuring. Check to the first to show me equivalent code using opacity!

Comment: Your code works as-is. http://jsfiddle.net/ZkfMS/

Comment: it seems to WORK, yes. But the new content seems to load either before, or at the same time as the fadeout effect

Comment: in what browser? testing in chrome, the new content doesn't appear until the element is completely faded out.

Comment: you are correct sir the code is indeed working. not sure how or why old code was cached in private browsing mode in firefox. oh well.

Comment: Private browsing does not stop caching, it just doesn't use the cache from currently opened non-private browsing windows and deletes the cache when the browser window is closed (not just the tab).

Answer (score 2):

Try this it's a little smoother...

```
$("#middle").fadeOut('slow',function(){
    $("#middle").html(data);
}).fadeIn('slow');
```

cheers!